# Unbound module Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, ocaml

I am trying to learn some OCaml, I created a very simple example to open and then close a sqlite file.

```
let () =
  let db = Sqlite3.db_open "test.db" in
  Sqlite3.db_close db
```

I did an `opam install sqlite3` and I see the .opam/default/lib/sqlite3 files in place. I would expect this means that the package is installed.

When I run `ocaml sqltest.ml` I would expect this to execute. Instead I get a `Error: Unbound module Sqlite3`

Even when I make it `ocaml -I +sqlite3 sqltest.ml` I get the same result. It's kind of hard to search for info on ocaml and most of the stuff I find is using `dune` or `ocamlbuild` or `ocamlfind` or something... I think that's fine, but in the interest of starting with the basics and building from there I would like to understand how all of the pieces are working. I'd imagine the basic `ocaml` or `ocamlc` should work in this simple case.

How do I make it understand where these libs are and use them? Why does it not understand it's own "default libs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ocamlfind to compile a trivial demonstration program that opens the Sqlite3 module.

```
$ cat test.ml
open Sqlite3

let () = print_endline "hello"
$ ocamlc test.ml
File "test.ml", line 1, characters 5-12:
1 | open Sqlite3
         ^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Sqlite3
$ ocamlfind ocamlc test.ml -package sqlite3 -linkpkg
$ ./a.out
hello
```

Alternative use of ocamlfind:

```
$ ocamlc -I `ocamlfind query sqlite3` sqlite3.cma test.ml
$ ./a.out
hello
```

As a side note, your code will not compile even with proper use of the compiler and ocamlfind because `Sqlite3.db_close` returns a boolean, you're trying to bind that expression to `()`. This is a type mismatch.

And you've opened `Sqlite3` so you don't need to use the fully qualified names. You might want to use [`let&`](http://mmottl.github.io/sqlite3-ocaml/api/sqlite3/Sqlite3/index.html#val-let&) to avoid the `db_close`.

```
open Sqlite3

let () =
  let& db = db_open "test.db" in
  print_endline "hello"
```

Comment: I see that the `ocamlfind` thing works... but why does it need that if the packages are already inside the default lib dir?

Comment: They're _not_. `sqlite3.cma` is in the `sqlite3` directory which is itself in `~/.opam/5.0.0/lib`.

Comment: Consult the `CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for directories that are automatically searched for dynamically loaded libraries.